# VBA Runtime Error '1004': Method 'MacroOptions' of object'_Application' failed

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I get this error right after opening a macro-enabled Excel workbook (Microsoft Office 365). The error window has four buttons: <kbd>Continue</kbd> (grayed-out), <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Debug</kbd> (grayed-out), and <kbd>Help</kbd>. The workbook contains one module with three simple subroutines, none of which use `Application.MacroOptions`. Below is the code in the module:

```
Sub CopyCMCTab()

On Error GoTo ErrExit
Call SpeedOn

Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim rng As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim facility As String
Dim template As String

Set Wb = Application.ThisWorkbook
Set rng = Wb.Sheets("Ref").Range("FACILITIES[facility]")
template = "CMC"

For Each c In rng 'Loop through all facilities

    If c.Value <> "CMC" Then

        facility = c.Value

        If facility = "CMMC" Then

            If Evaluate("ISREF('" & facility & "'!A1)") Then
                Wb.Sheets(facility).Delete
            End If

            Wb.Sheets(template).Copy after:=Wb.Sheets(Wb.Sheets.Count)
            ActiveSheet.Name = facility

        End If

    End If

Next c

Call SpeedOff
Exit Sub
ErrExit:
MsgBox Err.Description
Call SpeedOff

End Sub

Sub SpeedOn()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End Sub

Sub SpeedOff()
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

I do NOT get this error upon executing the code above, only RIGHT AFTER opening the workbook. I have searched other posts and forums, but none of the suggestions resolved the issue.

UPDATE: Although I did not determine the cause of this error, after rebooting, it did not appear the first time I opened the workbook. However, after closing and reopening the workbook, the error is appearing again. This error has appeared occasionally in the previous few weeks in different workbooks.

Comment: Why have you posted this code - why do you think this is run when you open the workbook? More likely you have workbook open code I'd have thought.

Comment: Continuing the idea of SJR -> Press Ctrl+F and search for the word "Open" in with check on "all modules".

Comment: I posted the code because it is the only macro-related content in the workbook. I searched the VBA project for the word "Open" and it was not found.

Comment: He says,"I get this error every time I open a macro-enabled Excel workbook (Microsoft Office 365)"

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser. Can you try holding shift down while you double click on the file.

Comment: The same error pops-up after holding down shift and opening the file by double-clicking on it.

Comment: Do you have any add-ins showing in the Project explorer?

Comment: Is the code in a Module or the Workbook? If it's in the workbook is it Public? Or you can try copying the Macro to a code module. If a code module is not available, create one by Insert Module

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Yes, I see "MathematicaLink", "QIMacrosforExcel", and "KutoolsforExcel".

Comment: @dbmitch As stated in the question stem, the code is in a module.

Comment: You can move the macro to a new module in a new excel and see if you get the same issue. Will at least help to possibly isolate the issue to a single workbook or something larger

Comment: @urdearboy Pasting the subroutines into a new module in a new workbook does not cause the run-time error upon opening the workbook. So perhpas the workbook is corrupted somehow?

Comment: Check the Workbook object in each of the Add-ins.  If there is a workbook OPEN procedure there, follow it to see if it calls a routine with your `.MacroOptions` property

Comment: Doesn’t seem like this is a add-in issue. The add-ins will carry over across books and the issue does not happen in a new book. Comment out your entire macro on your workbook, save it, and re-open it?

Comment: How about saving it as an .xlsx, then copy the codes, back into modules, and save as a .xlsm, see if the problem persists.

Comment: @urdearboy Ah, I had not seen the response indicating the problem was confined to a single workbook.

Comment: @Davesexcel I saved the workbook as .xlsx. I opened it and received the same error as before. So the error is occuring even in this .xlsx workbook. I opened another macro-enabled workbook, but did not get this error.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I cannot view the workbook objects in these add-ins since they are passwork protected in th eproject explorer.

Comment: Hmmm.  When you get the error message, is there a `DEBUG` key on the dialog window?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Yes, the error message dialog window does have a [DEBUG] key, but it is grayed-out.

Comment: The fact that `DEBUG` is grayed out suggests that the error is coming from a password protected project -- likely one of those add-ins.  Try disabling the addins and see if the error goes away when you re-open the book.